# Import definition in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import

I created an Import Definition in a Data Extension to import Data from another Data Extension. In [Create an Import Definition docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_a_new_import_definition.htm&type=5), says:

> Once you complete your import definition, you can include that definition in an automation via Automation Studio.

When I go to Automation Studio the only activity that (I think) could be the activity to run this import definition would be the "Import File" Activity, but when I create a new one, the only option is to get files from FTP.

How can I run this Import Definition automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to create this import definition within contact builder > imports

Then if the file import activity these imports are visible:

[image: import activity]

You can also leverage a [SQL activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) to move data to/from DEs

> A query is an activity that retrieves data extension or data view information matching your criteria, then includes that information in a data extension. You use SQL to create the query you use in the query activity. You provide a name, external key, and description to identify and describe the activity within the application interface and for API calls. A query activity executes your SQL statements for up to 30 minutes. Query activities exceeding this limit display an error status and do not output results.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement is to have the Data from one Data Extension to the other using an Automated Process. In this case, you need to create a Scheduled Automation with the following three Activities.

1. Data Extract Activity with the Extract Type "Data Extension Extract".
2. File Transfer Activity with the option "Move File from a Safehouse".
3. Import Activity onto your Targeted Data Extension.

In all the 3 steps, you must have the File Naming Pattern the same (eg: test.csv).